# Storing and updating lists in Python dictionaries: why does this happen?

Tags: python, dictionary, list

I have a list of data that looks like the following:

```
// timestep,x_position,y_position
0,4,7
0,2,7
0,9,5
0,6,7
1,2,5
1,4,7
1,9,0
1,6,8
```

... and I want to make this look like:

```
0, (4,7), (2,7), (9,5), (6,7)
1, (2,5), (4,7), (9,0), (6.8)
```

My plan was to use a dictionary, where the value of t is the key for the dictionary, and the value against the key would be a list. I could then append each (x,y) to the list. Something like:

```
# where t = 0, c = (4,7), d = {}

# code 1
d[t].append(c)
```

Now this causes IDLE to fail. However, if I do:

```
# code 2
d[t] = []
d[t].append(c)
```

... this works.

So the question is: why does code 2 work, but code 1 doesn't?

PS Any improvement on what I'm planning on doing would be of great interest!! I think I will have to check the dictionary on each loop through the input to see if the dictionary key already exists, I guess by using something like max(d.keys()): if it is there, append data, if not create the empty list as the dictionary value, and then append data on the next loop through.

Comment: "Idle fails?"  Not very meaningful.  Please provide the actual error message.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Let's look at

```
d[t].append(c)
```

What is the value of `d[t]`?  Try it.

```
d = {}
t = 0
d[t]
```

What do you get?  Oh.  There's nothing in `d` that has a key of `t`.

Now try this.

```
d[t] = []
d[t]
```

Ahh.  Now there's something in `d` with a key of `t`.

There are several things you can do.

1. Use example 2.
2. Use `setdefault`.  `d.setdefault(t,[]).append(c)`.
3. Use [collections.defaultdict](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/defaultdict-objects.html).  You'd use a `defaultdict(list)` instead of a simple dictionary, `{}`.

---

**Edit 1.  Optimization**

Given input lines from a file in the above form: ts, x, y, the grouping process is needless.  There's no reason to go from a simple list of ( ts, x, y ) to a more complex
list of ( ts, (x,y), (x,y), (x,y), ... ).  The original list can be processed exactly as it arrived.

```
d= collections.defaultdict(list)
for ts, x, y in someFileOrListOrQueryOrWhatever:
    d[ts].append( (x,y) )
```

---

**Edit 2.  Answer Question**

"when initialising a dictionary, you need to tell the dictionary what the key-value data structure will look like?"

I'm not sure what the question means.  Since, all dictionaries *are* key-value structures, the question's not very clear.  So, I'll review the three alternatives, which may answer the question.

**Example 2**.

Initialization

```
d= {}
```

Use

```
if t not in d:
    d[t] = list()
d[t].append( c )
```

Each dictionary value must be initialized to some useful structure.  In this case, we check to see if the key is present; when the key is missing, we create the key and assign an empty list.

**Setdefault**

Initialization

```
d= {}
```

Use

```
d.setdefault(t,list()).append( c )
```

In this case, we exploit the `setdefault` method to either fetch a value associated with a key or create a new value associated with a missing key.

**default dict**

Initialization

```
import collections
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
```

Use

```
d[t].append( c )
```

The `defaultdict` uses an initializer function for missing keys.  In this case, we provide the `list` function so that a new, empty list is created for a missing key.

Comment: So does this mean that when initialising a dictionary, you need to tell the dictionary what the key-value data structure will look like?

Sorry, coming from a Perl background which I have not used in anger in years, so may be going on broken memories, as was sure you could do this anonymously.

Answer (score 12):

I think you want to use setdefault. It's a bit weird to use but does exactly what you need.

```
d.setdefault(t, []).append(c)
```

The `.setdefault` method will return the element (in our case, a list) that's bound to the dict's key `t` if that key exists. If it doesn't, it will bind an empty list to the key `t` and return it. So either way, a list will be there that the `.append` method can then append the tuple `c` to.

Answer (score 1):

```
dict=[]  //it's not a dict, it's a list, the dictionary is dict={}
elem=[1,2,3]
dict.append(elem)
```

you can access the single element in this way:

```
print dict[0] // 0 is the index
```

the output will be:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Python is confusing enough with it's irregular bracketing to add to it by taking a function name ( dict() should return an empty dict ) similar to a data structure and make it a variable.

Answer (score 1):

In the case your data is not already sorted by desired criteria, here's the code that might help to group the data:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
$ cat data_shuffled.txt
0,2,7
1,4,7
0,4,7
1,9,0
1,2,5
0,6,7
1,6,8
0,9,5
"""
from itertools   import groupby
from operator    import itemgetter

# load the data and make sure it is sorted by the first column
sortby_key = itemgetter(0)
data = sorted((map(int, line.split(',')) for line in open('data_shuffled.txt')),
              key=sortby_key)

# group by the first column
grouped_data = []
for key, group in groupby(data, key=sortby_key):
    assert key == len(grouped_data) # assume the first column is 0,1, ...
    grouped_data.append([trio[1:] for trio in group])

# print the data
for i, pairs in enumerate(grouped_data):
    print i, pairs
```

Output:

```
0 [[2, 7], [4, 7], [6, 7], [9, 5]]
1 [[4, 7], [9, 0], [2, 5], [6, 8]]
```