# reading into two dictionaries from same file (python)

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I'm trying to read a text file into two dictionaries with values as a list.

The file contains the following:

```
term1  doc1 doc3 doc4
term2  doc5 doc1
term3  doc6 doc2
```

I'm trying to create two dictionaries from the same file, one that will have the terms as keys and values as docs and the other will be the opposite.

```
inverted_index = {}
forward_index = {}
with open('term_sample.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        items = line.split()
        term, doc = items[0], items[1:]
        for doc in items[1:]
            inverted_index[term] = [doc]
            forward_index[doc] = [term]

print(inverted_index)
print(forward_index)
```

with what I've done so far I'm getting the following output:

```
{'term2': ['doc1'], 'term1': ['doc4'], 'term3': ['doc2']}
{'doc3': ['term1'], 'doc6': ['term3'], 'doc4': ['term1'], 'doc5': ['term2'], 'doc1': ['term2'], 'doc2': ['term3']}
```

but this is the output I'm looking for:

```
{'term1': ['doc1','doc3','doc4'], 'term2': ['doc5','doc1'], 'term3': ['doc6','doc2']}
{'doc1': ['term1','term2'], 'doc3': ['term1'], 'doc4': ['term1'], 'doc5': ['term2'], 'doc6': ['term3'], 'doc2': ['term3']}
```

Please help me to fix this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to add to `inverted_index` in the inner loop, that's just done once for each row.

In the inner loop, you need to append to the dictionary entry if it already exists, not overwrite it.

```
inverted_index = {}
forward_index = {}
with open('term_sample.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        items = line.split()
        term, doc = items[0], items[1:]
        inverted_index[term] = doc
        for doc in items[1:]
            forward_index.setdefault(doc, []).append(term)

print(inverted_index)
print(forward_index)
```

Comment: FWIW, this also works with an empty list literal `[]` (instead of calling the `list()` constructor) to provide the default object for `.setdefault`.

Comment: @PM2Ring Good point. I was just copying the code from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327534/storing-and-updating-lists-in-python-dictionaries-why-does-this-happen)

Comment: Now I see both styles are there in different places.

Comment: Some people prefer to use `list()`, because it makes it explicit that it's a new list. I prefer the literal because it's cheaper than a `list()` call. Of course, if you did something like `empty_list = []` outside the loop and used `.setdefault(doc, empty_list)` it _would_ do the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `defaultdict(list)` from `collections` module - cause in your solution every time the key gets updated:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 

from collections import defaultdict

inverted_index = defaultdict(list)
forward_index = defaultdict(list)
with open('term_sample.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        items = line.split()
        term, doc = items[0], items[1:]
        for doc in items[1:]:
            inverted_index[term].append(doc)
            forward_index[doc].append(term)

print(inverted_index)
print(forward_index)
```

Answer (score 1):

`inverted_index` should not in the inner `for`, and for `forward_index`, you replaced the previous value in each inner `for`. Try the following code:

```
inverted_index = {}
forward_index = {}
with open('test') as f:
    for line in f:
        items = line.split()
        term, docs = items[0], items[1:]
        inverted_index[term] = docs
        for doc in docs:
            terms = forward_index.get(doc, [])
            terms.append(term)
            forward_index[doc] = terms

print(inverted_index)
print(forward_index)
```

Answer (score 1):

As 'coder' suggested, I would also use a `defaultdict` here. Because the `doc`s may appear more than once across multiple `term`s, you should use a `set` to avoid duplicate items:

```
from collections import defaultdict

inverted_index = defaultdict(set)
forward_index = defaultdict(list)
with open('term_sample.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        items = line.split()
        term, docs = items[0], items[1:]
        inverted_index[term].update(docs)
        for doc in docs:
            forward_index[doc].append(term)

print(inverted_index)
print(forward_index)
```

(And as Barmar suggests, you only need to assign the `forward_index` once in the outer loop.)

Comment: Can you please explain to me what is "defaultdict"? :)

Comment: With a `defaultdict`, if there is a key that does not have any value, you can set what that value is by default without having it raise a `KeyError`. [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Comment: but here, it throws an error " TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' " in "forward_index[doc].add(term), did you mean inverted_index here instead?

Comment: Hi, I apologize but my logic was wrong. It is updated now.